# A problem on path-wise connectedness

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}| x=0,-1 \leq y \leq 1\}$, $G=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|  \ 0<x \leq 1, y=\text{sin}(\frac{1}{x})\}$ and $A=K\bigcup G.$

Claim: $A$ is not pathwise connected.

Proof: Let $u=(0,1),v=(1,\text{sin}1).$ Suppose there is a parametrized path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R^2}$ in $A$ joining $u$ to $v.$ Define $t_*=\text{sup}\{t \in[0,1] : \ \gamma[0,t] \subseteq K\}$

Let $p_i:\mathbb{R^2} \to\mathbb{R}$ be the $i$-th component projection, $i=1,2.$

Could anyone advise me on how to show that $p_2$ o  $\gamma$ is not continuous at $t_*$ ?

Do I construct a sequence $(t_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $[0,t_*)$ such that $t_n \to t_*$ but $p_2(\gamma(t_n))$ $\not \to p_2(\gamma(t_*))$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider $[t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon)$. Since $p_1\circ\gamma$ must contain a $[0,\delta]$, what can you say about $p_2\circ\gamma$?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. But here's what I gathered: $-1 \leq p_2(\gamma(x)) \leq 1, \forall x \in [0,1] ?$

Comment: What can you say about $\{ p_2(\gamma(t)) : t \in [t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon) \}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma$ were a path in $A$ connecting $(0,1)$ and $(1,\sin 1)$, then

$$t_\ast = \sup \{ t \in [0,1] : \gamma(t)\in K\} < 1.$$

So for all small enough $\varepsilon > 0$, the interval $[t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon]$ is contained in the parameter interval $[0,1]$. Since $p_1$ and $\gamma$ are continuous, and $x_\varepsilon :=p_1(\gamma(t_\ast+\varepsilon)) > 0$, we have

$$[0,x_\varepsilon] \subset p_1(\gamma([t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon])).$$

That means $\gamma((t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon]) \supset \{(x,\sin \frac1x) : x \in (0,x_\varepsilon]\}$, since to every $x \in (0,1]$, there is a unique $y\in [-1,1]$ with $(x,y) \in A$. And hence

$$p_2(\gamma([t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon])) \supset p_2\left(\left\{(x,\sin \frac1x) : x \in (0,x_\varepsilon]\right\}\right) = [-1,1].$$

Thus $p_2\circ\gamma$ is not continuous in $t_\ast$, hence $\gamma$ is not continuous in $t_\ast$, which contradicts the assumption (that $\gamma$ is a path in $A$, i.e. a continuous map $[0,1] \to A$).

Comment: I have shown that $p_2(\gamma(t))$ attains every value in $[-1,1]$ on every interval $(t_\ast,\,t_\ast+\varepsilon)$. Rename $\varepsilon$ to $\delta$, and choose $\epsilon_0 < 1$, and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I still don't understand how you establish that $[0, x_\epsilon] \subset p_1(\gamma([t_*, t_*+ \epsilon])). $

Comment: Intermediate value theorem. By assumption, $p_1\circ \gamma$ is continuous. So every value between $0 = p_1(\gamma(t_\ast))$ and $x_\varepsilon = p_1(\gamma(t_\ast+\varepsilon))$ is attained between $t_\ast$ and $t_\ast+\varepsilon$. Possibly also some values $> x_\varepsilon$, but we are not interested in those.